# Shopware 6 App - Twig Script causes memory overflow

Tags: twig, shopware6, shopware6-app

We have written us a script that allows us in Shopware 6 badges per categories. With many products crashes sometime after 5 minutes shopware crashes with the log message that the memory at php is not enough.

**Have we done anything wrong here?**

We have already packed the elements in an array (the graphics) and fetch them bundled from the server.

```
{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}
{% set page = hook.page %}
{# @var page \Shopware\Storefront\Page\Product\ProductPage #}

{% set products = [] %}  

{% if hook.page.cmsPage.type === 'product_list' %}
    {% foreach hook.page.cmsPage.sections as section %}
        {% foreach section.blocks as sectionBlock %}
            {% if sectionBlock.type !== 'product-listing' %}
                {% continue %}
            {% endif %}

            {% foreach sectionBlock.slots as slot %}
                {% if slot.type !== 'product-listing' %}
                    {% continue %}
                {% endif %}

                {% foreach slot.data.listing.entities as product %}
                    {% set products = products|merge([product]) %}
                {% endforeach %}
            {% endforeach %}
        {% endforeach %}
    {% endforeach %}
{% endif %}

{% set categoryIds = products|reduce((carry, v) => carry|merge(v.categoryTree), []) %}
{% if categoryIds %}
    {% set categories = services.repository.search('category', {'ids': categoryIds}) %}

    {% set mediaIds = [] %}

    {# Loop through all products and collect media ids #}
    {% foreach products as product %}
        {% set badgeList = [] %}

        {% foreach categories.entities.getList(product.categoryTree) as category %}
            {% if category.customFields.minds_cd_show_badge %}
                {% set badgeList = badgeList|merge([{
                    'priority': category.customFields.minds_cd_badge_priority,
                    'mediaId': category.customFields.minds_cd_badge
                }]) %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endforeach %}

        {% set badge = (badgeList|sort((a, b) => a.priority <=> b.priority))|last %}

        {% if badge %}
            {% set mediaIds = mediaIds|merge([ badge.mediaId ]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endforeach %}

    {# Get all badge media ids in a performant way #}
    {% set mediaCollection = services.repository.search('media', {'ids': mediaIds}) %}

    {# Loop through all products again and attach the badge #}
    {% foreach products as product %}
        {% set badgeList = [] %}

        {% foreach categories.entities.getList(product.categoryTree) as category %}
            {% if category.customFields.minds_cd_show_badge %}
                {% set badgeList = badgeList|merge([{
                    'priority': category.customFields.minds_cd_badge_priority,
                    'mediaId': category.customFields.minds_cd_badge
                }]) %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endforeach %}

        {% set badge = (badgeList|sort((a, b) => a.priority <=> b.priority))|last %}

        {% if badge %}
            {% set badgeMedia = mediaCollection.get(badge.mediaId) %}

            {% do product.addArrayExtension('mcb', {
                'badge': badgeMedia
            }) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endforeach %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Any reason you're doing all this overhead inside the template and not in a controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think a real performance killer here might be that you potentially fetch a **lot** of categories. At least that could be the case if the category tree has many levels, with many categories on each level and products are assigned to multiple categories on different branches.

If I read this correctly you're really only interested in categories that have the custom field `minds_cd_show_badge` set to `true`. I assume those would potentially far less categories than the total number of entities you're fetching right now.

You could try setting a filter in your criteria targeting your custom field so you're only fetching the categories that are relevant in your case.

```
{% set criteria = {
    'ids': categoryIds,
    'filter': [
        { 'field': 'customFields.minds_cd_show_badge', 'type': 'equals', 'value': true }
    ]
} %}

{% set categories = services.repository.search('category', criteria) %}
```